# Android - how to make content views fit a layout?

Tags: android, layout, view, textview

I have multiple View with different width.
 I want to put them into a layout from left to right, from top to bottom. 
I don't want to have fixed columns; 
Instead, I want fill a row with View as many as possible until the row is full.
When a row is full, then fill next row.

For example(same number as same view)
112222333345555666
7777777777888888
99999900000000000

Another example is the Gmail sender address:
[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: What should happen if the row is full? Go to the next line or cut off the text?

Comment: @barq I've just edited and give one more example. I want to fill one line and then next line

Comment: @barq I've tried put views into different layouts like TableLayout and Linear Layout and that's all, because I don't know how to achieve it and stuck with this. I've googled a bit, but not found related solution

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @barq thanks for help, I just found what I want. please see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that provides the exact layout I want.
It's called FlowLayout.
https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout